# getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment) return null on GoogleMaps Android App

Tags: android, google-maps

Estaba desarrollando una App en Android que implementa un fragment en el que pretendo cargar un GoogleMapsActivity, pero en vez de implementarlo con activity la idea es hacerlo en una fragment, ya que mi App se basa en el Android Component Navigation, que navega entre fragments.

Creo que he realizado todos los registros en los servicios de google correctamente, pero al intentar la lanzar el mapa en mi App, obtengo una NullpointerException:

```
Process: com.example.journal, PID: 5750
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.journal.ui.search.ItemBirdFragment.onCreate(ItemBirdFragment.java:92)
```

El código de mi fragment es el siguiente:

ItemBirdFragment.fragment

```
public class ItemBirdFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

...

@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Bundle mapViewBundle = new Bundle();
        if(outState != null){
            outState.putBundle(Constants.MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY, mapViewBundle);
            mapView.onSaveInstanceState(mapViewBundle);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se ha podido cargar la localización del ave selecionada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //TODO:Prueba Maps.

        OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                appNavigator.goBack(requireActivity());
            }
        };
        requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_bird, container, false);
        initView(root);
        initGoogleMap(savedInstanceState);
     

        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getContext());

        if(status  == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }else{
            Dialog diolog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, (Activity)getContext(), 10);
            diolog.show();
        }
        initListeners();
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void initListeners() {
        btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initView(View root) {
        Serializable serializable = getArguments().getSerializable("item");
        bird = (Bird) serializable;
        bird_name = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.bird_name);
        sci_name = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.sci_name);
        data_date = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.date_data);
        location_name = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.location_name);
        quantity = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        bird_image = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.bird_image);
        btn_add = (FloatingActionButton) root.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
        quantity_image = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.quantity_image);
        loading = (ProgressBar) root.findViewById(R.id.loading_bird);
        scroll_bird = (ScrollView) root.findViewById(R.id.scroll_bird);
        mapView = (MapView) root.findViewById(R.id.map_fragment);
        scroll_bird.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        loading.animate()
                .alpha(1f)
                .setDuration(3000)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        loading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        scroll_bird.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
        bird_name.setText(bird.getComName());
        sci_name.setText(bird.getSciName());
        data_date.setText(bird.getDate());
        location_name.setText(bird.getLocName());

        if (bird.getHowMany() == "0") {
            quantity.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            quantity_image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else
            quantity.setText(bird.getHowMany() + " " + getString(R.string.birds_seen));

        if (!bird.getUrlImg().equals(Bird.ERROR_IMAGE)) {
            Picasso.with(getContext()).load(bird.getUrlImg()).transform(new CropSquareTransformation()).resize(800, 600).into(bird_image);
        } else {
            bird_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_broken_image);
        }
        //TODO: Video
    }

    private void openDialog() {
        //TODO: Before to send to the add
        DialogFragment dialogFragment = new AddDialog(getContext(), bird);
        dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "AddDialog");
    }

    private void initGoogleMap(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // *** IMPORTANT ***
        // MapView requires that the Bundle you pass contain _ONLY_ MapView SDK
        // objects or sub-Bundles.
        Bundle mapViewBundle = null;

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle(Constants.MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
            mapView.onCreate(mapViewBundle);
            mapView.onResume();
            mapView.getMapAsync(this);
        } else {
            onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        }
    }

    private void setCameraView() {
        if(map != null){
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(bird.getLat()), Double.parseDouble(bird.getLng()))));
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(
                    new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(bird.getLat()), Double.parseDouble(bird.getLng()))));
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se han podido cargar los detalles de localización del ave", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(mapView!=null){
            mapView.onResume();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se han podido cargar los detalles de localización del ave", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(mapView!=null){
            mapView.onStart();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se han podido cargar los detalles de localización del ave", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(mapView!=null){
            mapView.onStop();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se han podido cargar los detalles de localización del ave", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        if(googleMap != null && map != null){
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            map = googleMap;
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

            UiSettings settings = map.getUiSettings();
            settings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

            setCameraView();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se han podido cargar los detalles de localización del ave", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if(mapView!=null){
            mapView.onPause();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se han podido cargar los detalles de localización del ave", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
      if(mapView!=null){
            mapView.onDestroy();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se han podido cargar los detalles de localización del ave", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        if(mapView!=null){
            mapView.onLowMemory();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se han podido cargar los detalles de localización del ave", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

y el archvo .xml que define la interfaz gráfica es el siguiente:

fragment_item__bird.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.search.ItemBirdFragment">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading_bird"
        style="?android:progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:progressTint="@color/dark_green"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_bird"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bird_name"
                style="@style/TitleDialogSimpleTextViewStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="-"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sci_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:text="-"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bird_name" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_wagtail"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_add"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView6" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bird_image"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sci_name"
                tools:src="@drawable/ic_broken_image" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date_data"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_calendar"
                android:drawablePadding="12dp"
                android:drawableTint="@color/super_dark_green"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bird_image" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/location_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_location"
                android:drawablePadding="12dp"
                android:drawableTint="@color/burgundy"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/quantity" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:background="@color/burgundy"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/location_name" />


            <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/quantity_image"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_bird"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/date_data" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/quantity"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:elegantTextHeight="false"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/quantity_image"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/date_data" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Como digo lo que esta llegando a null, aunque esta inicializado es 'mapFragment'.

Si podeís ayudar, muchas gracias de ante mano!

[EDIT]

He actualizado el código, situando la linea que lanzaba el error en el onCreatedView(), pero sigue dando el mismo error.

Añado también una captura del debugger:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La línea que te genera error debe ir en el onCreateView.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario! He actualizado los cambios, y el map fragment sigue llegando a null.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar cómo ha quedado el código en base a la modificación que hiciste?

Comment: Ya esta actualizado

Comment: te dejo un [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53059054/android-google-map-in-fragment-always-show-the-supportmapfragment-was-null) que te puede servir, avísanos como te fue

Comment: no me soluciono el prolema.